# The figure-eight is not a regular manifold of $R^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The figure-eight is the image of $f$, where $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin 2t),-\pi /2 <t<3\pi /2.$

How to use the definition of regular submanifold to deduce that the figure-eight is not a regular manifold of $\Bbb R^2$?

In Tu's book, it mentions that there exits a cross at the origin , and hence the figure eight is not regular.

Comment: What's the definition of "regular" manifold?

Comment: What does every neighborhood of the origin in this set look like? Does it fit the definition?

Comment: A subset $S$ of a manifold $N$ of dimension $n $ is regular submanifold of dimension $k$ if for every $p\in S$, there is a coordinate nieghborhood (U,ϕ)=(U,x1,x2,...,xn)of p in the atlas of N such that U∩S is defined by the vanishing of n−k of the coordinate function

Comment: How to show that there does not exist such coordinate neighborhood?

Comment: Don’t bother yourself with the definition of regular sub manifold. The figure 8 is not a manifold. What happens to the topology of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ once you remove a point? What will happen to an open set around the origin once you removed the origin?. Can the open set around the origin be homemorphic to an open subset of the reals?